# Email with attachment app is getting crash - Android

Tags: android

i have two java class one for sending simple(text) email and another one is with attachment. Fist one is working fine but second one i.e  email with attachment class is not working . My app is getting crash and i am not able to figure it out what is happening wrong :

**NewEmailAttachmentSender.java :**

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class NewEmailAttachmentSender {

   private static final String username = "123@gmail.com";
    private static final String password = "12345";

    public NewEmailAttachmentSender() {  }

    public void sendEmailWithAttachments(String email, String subject, String messageBody, String FilePath)
    {
        Session session = createSessionObject();
        try {
            final Message message = createMessage(email, subject, messageBody, FilePath, session);

            Thread t = new Thread(){                

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Transport.send(message);
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        //TODO Handle Exception
                    }
                }
            };

            t.start();

            //new SendMailTask().execute(message);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private Message createMessage(String email, String subject, String messageBody, String FilePath, Session session) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        //Log.i("check","createingMessage");
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);  
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("123@gmail.com", "POST"));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("123@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(messageBody);
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
        // creates message part
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(FilePath);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(source.getName());
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        message.setContent(multipart);
        return message;
    }


    private Session createSessionObject() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        return Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication( username, password);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Main activity :**

```
import com.post.gmailSender.GmailSender;
import com.post.gmailSender.NewEmailAttachmentSender;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void gmailSender(View view)
    {

        Log.d("tag","clicked");

         GmailSender sender = new GmailSender();

        try {   

            sender.sendMail("123@gmail.com", "Test Mail", "Post TestMail");
            //sender.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {   
            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
        } 

    }


    public void gmailwithattachment(View view)
    {
        Log.d("tag","clicked");

        NewEmailAttachmentSender sender = new NewEmailAttachmentSender();
        try {
            sender.sendEmailWithAttachments("123@gmail.com", "Test Mail", "Post TestMail","/sdcard/logo.png");

        } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e); 
        }




    }



}
```

**Logcat:**

```
08-11 15:58:22.226: E/AndroidRuntime(11763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 15:58:22.226: E/AndroidRuntime(11763): Process: com.post.post, PID: 11763
08-11 15:58:22.226: E/AndroidRuntime(11763): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method gmailAttchmentSender(View) in the activity class com.post.post.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button2'
08-11 15:58:22.226: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3810)
08-11 15:58:22.226: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-11 15:58:22.226: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-11 15:58:22.226: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-11 15:58:22.226: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-11 15:58:22.226: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-11 15:58:22.226: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
```

Comment: Are you specifying the onClickListener in your XML layout resource? It seems you're using `gmailAttchmentSender` instead of maybe `gmailwithattachment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason for crash .

Mistake i was doing in layout section i.e

android:text="gmailwithattachment" 
  android:onClick="gmailAttchmentSender"

above lines were written worng by me. now crash is not happening but email with attachment also not getting send . i am not getting any error either :(

Comment: Hi now i am able to send attachment mail . i was missing  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> permission as it is required . please follow the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html for mor information